# How to check version between Database and Webservice?

Tags: ios, database, web-services, uicollectionview

How can i check data from database when i call Webservice?

I'm use this when I call database in device
`Listname = [db getdata];` but i need to check data on Database with Webservice. I can use this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[Listname objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]coverURL]];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    [db initWithDB];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        shelfcell.bookCover.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
});
```

I can show image from Web service and I can show image from Database but I don't know how to check data i know to check only use `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` when tap image will check data but how to get data from `cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I need both data to check version.//Big Thanks for Any Idea

---

Edit

I'm use `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` for check

```
            if([db isDownloaded:ListName ListVersion:[ListVersion floatValue]]){


                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"reader" sender:self];
            }
            else{

                [self startDownload];
            }
```

This my database for check

```
-(BOOL)isDownloaded:(NSString*)ListName ListVersion:(float)ListVersion {
.....
 NSString *tempBook = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 3)];
                float tempBookVr = (float)sqlite3_column_double(searchStatement, 5);
                NSString *tempVersion = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)sqlite3_column_double(searchStatement, 5)] stringValue];
                if ([ListName isEqualToString:tempBook]) {
                    if (ListVersion == tempBookVr) {                       
                        sqlite3_finalize(searchStatement);
                        return YES;
                    }
                    else
                    {
.....
    }
```

This one is work for `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` but I don't know about `cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` for check // Thank for Any Idea.

Comment: What is the purpose of the check? This is a user requested refresh? Or a time based expiry and refresh?

Comment: I just need to check like this  `if(VersionListfromDatabaseDevice == VersionListfromWebservice){ do something..... }` Guide me please

Comment: We don't know your code, describe the requirement, not what code you think you need. Is this a version number check? Or a check that all of your image URLs match? Why can't you use the code you show, why doesn't it work?

Comment: oh i see sorry. ill edit question.